# A limit of the hyperfactorial and Barnes G-function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I'm doing some work on the various means (arithmetic, geometric, etc.) of some sequences of binomial coefficients, and I'm having some trouble proving a result regarding a ratio of the [Hyperfactorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html) and the [Barnes G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html). In particular,
$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\dfrac{H(n)}{G(n+2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n^2+n}}
$$
where $H(n)$ is the hyperfactorial and $G(n)$ is the Barnes G-function. Since
$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}} = e
$$
I squared the first limit and reduced it to
$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{H(n)^{\frac{4}{n^2+n}}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}^2}.
$$
I'm stuck at a wall trying to prove that the first limit converges to $\sqrt{e}$ (or equivalently that the last limit converges to $e$). Tantalizingly, Mathematica confirms that in both cases this is correct but the Trace[] function offers no help; it simply directly makes the jump from the full expression to the final result. Can anyone give me some pointers on where to go? Thanks a ton!